# Can I specify custom range types in the "Accept-Ranges" header?

Tags: http, http-headers

A common "accept-ranges" header is bytes.  However, it makes sense to me that there could be dozens of other types of ranges.

I'm writing an API resource that takes a date range.  Would it make sense to specify date in the accept-ranges header and expect the range header from the client?

Answer (score 4):

I have been researching the same subject as the Accept-Ranges & Range headers seems like a good candidates for passing paging data.

The HTTP1.1 spec states:

> range-unit = bytes-unit | **other-range-unit**

which suggests that you could use your own unit types, but then goes on to say

> The only range unit defined by HTTP/1.1 is bytes. HTTP/1.1 implementations MAY ignore ranges specified using other units.

Although the only range unit supported is bytes, the statement does emphasise that HTTP 1.1 MAY (not should) ignore ranges in other units - so maybe its up to you?

But, HTTP headers contain data related to the message body not what the message body represents, so only supporting bytes-units makes sense as a byte range can be applied to the message body no matter what resource it represents. Whereas a date range is a context based range and is only applicable in certain situations.

As you mentioned in your question a way to implement the date range would be to supply a custom *Accept-Ranges* header in the response to a HEAD or OPTIONS request for that URL, then pass the *Range* header with any GET requests to the same URL

I think it is up to the developer whether to use it this way, but to me the hole is a bit too round for this square peg! Pass the values in the query string.

**Reference:**

```
3.12 Range Units

HTTP/1.1 allows a client to request that only part (a range of) the response entity be included within the response. HTTP/1.1 uses range units in the Range (section 14.35) and Content-Range (section 14.16) header fields. An entity can be broken down into subranges according to various structural units.

      range-unit       = bytes-unit | *other-range-unit*
      bytes-unit       = "bytes"
      other-range-unit = token

The only range unit defined by HTTP/1.1 is "bytes". HTTP/1.1 implementations MAY ignore ranges specified using other units.

HTTP/1.1 has been designed to allow implementations of applications that do not depend on knowledge of ranges.
```

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.12

Comment: You really should stop looking at RFC 2616; we've been working on http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p5-range-21.html for a reason.